# Crystal Reports Cross Tab sort

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

I have a cross tab 
the data table is consist of category and number.
the source table for the cross tab looks like this

```
category | number | month year | zSort
-----------------------------------------------------
All      |  0.25  | YTD 2017   | zAll
Apple    |  1.23  | MAR 2017   | Apple
Orange   |  1.10  | FEB 2017   | Orange
Apple    |  2.20  | FEB 2017   | Apple
Apple    |  1.11  | YTD 2017   | Apple
```

and so on  ....

and my goal is the cross tab will end up looking like this

```
       |FEB 2017|MAR 2017|YTD 2017
-------------------------------------
Apple  | 2.20   |  1.23  | 1.11
Orange | #.##   |  #.##  | #.##
All    | #.##   |  #.##  | #.##
```

But I am having problem with sorting . currently my cross tab is looking like this. notice category **all** is on the top instead of on the bottom.

```
       |FEB 2017|MAR 2017|YTD 2017
-------------------------------------
All    | #.##   |  #.##  | #.##
Apple  | 2.20   |  1.23  | 1.11
Orange | #.##   |  #.##  | #.##
```

what I have done is to use zSort in my group sort expert

- first I add zSort in my summarized fields, and set to min value
- then in my group sort expert I select sort all and select based on
  "min of @zSort" ascending

but it does not seem to work..

please help?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize the sorting actually works but it was in incorrect order.

so even I set it to ascending, crystal somehow sort it descending.

I change in group sort expert to descending and it is all working fine!!

so it works in reversed order ascending is descending and descending is ascending LOL...

thank you